# How can I use the dictionary application in my language?

Tags: gnome, internationalization, language-support, dictionary

I want to use the Dictionary app (**Applications>Office>Dictionary**) bundled with Ubuntu in my own language, Portuguese (Portugal).

In the application preferences I've the option to add alternative dictionaries, but I've to get trough all sort of complicated and not user-friendly at all definitions.

[image]

In the **Add Dictionary** windows, I've a tab that should have the list of available dictionaries, but even after refreshing it only shows blank.

So, is there an easy way to add an alternative language (in my case, PT-pt) to the Dictionary application?

**Fact:**  Please don't suggest alternative programas. I really want to use the default application.

Comment: I would like that, too. But I'm in for brasilian portuguese

Comment: Do you mean a translation dictionary or a dictionary that explains words?

Comment: A dictionary that explains words. Like the default dictionary application does, but I would like to have it in my mother tongue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a similar question https://answers.launchpad.net/gnome-utils/+question/706.
Unfortunately, I don't see a Portuguese [DICT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DICT) server on the [list](http://luetzschena-stahmeln.de/dictd/index.php).